# Adding items to Realm database changes some variables

Tags: android, database, list, realm, realm-list

This is the code I have:

```
for (SearchData searchData1 : searchDataTemp){
                            Log.i("", "test is favourite searchdata:" + searchData1.getIs_favorite() + "..name: " + searchData1.getTitle());
                        }
 Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getActivity());
                            realm.beginTransaction();
                            List<SearchData> managedSeachData = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(searchDataTemp);
                            realm.commitTransaction();
for (SearchData searchData1 : managedSeachData) {
                                Log.i("", "test is favourite searchdata:" + searchData1.getIs_favorite() + "..name: " + searchData1.getTitle());
                                user.getRecents().add(searchData1);
                            }
```

This is what I get for the normal list in my logs:

```
test is favourite searchdata:true..name: Vondelpark
```

This is what I get for the managed Realmlist in my logs:

```
test is favourite searchdata:false..name: Vondelpark
```

Any ideea how this can be fixed?

PS: This is my SearchData model:

```
public class SearchData extends RealmObject{
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String title;
private String subtitle;
private String reference;
private String place_id;
private boolean is_favorite;
private int timestamp;
private String last_travel_mode;
private Geometry geometry;
private double distance;
private boolean close;
private int visited_count;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getSubtitle() {
    return subtitle;
}

public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
}

public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}

public void setReference(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

public String getPlace_id() {
    return place_id;
}

public void setPlace_id(String place_id) {
    this.place_id = place_id;
}

public boolean getIs_favorite() {
    return is_favorite;
}

public void setIs_favorite(boolean is_favorite) {
    this.is_favorite = is_favorite;
}

public int getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(int timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getLast_travel_mode() {
    return last_travel_mode;
}

public void setLast_travel_mode(String last_travel_mode) {
    this.last_travel_mode = last_travel_mode;
}

public Geometry getGeometry() {
    return geometry;
}

public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
    this.geometry = geometry;
}

public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(double distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}

public boolean isClose() {
    return close;
}

public void setClose(boolean close) {
    this.close = close;
}

public boolean is_favorite() {
    return is_favorite;
}

public int getVisited_count() {
    return visited_count;
}

public void setVisited_count(int visited_count) {
    this.visited_count = visited_count;
}

public SearchData() {
}

public SearchData(String id, String title, String subtitle, String reference, String place_id, boolean is_favorite, int timestamp, String last_travel_mode , int visited_count){
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
    this.reference = reference;
    this.place_id = place_id;
    this.is_favorite = is_favorite;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.last_travel_mode = last_travel_mode;
    this.visited_count = visited_count;
}

public SearchData(String id, String title, String subtitle, String reference, String place_id, boolean is_favorite, int timestamp, String last_travel_mode, Geometry geometry , int visited_count){
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
    this.reference = reference;
    this.place_id = place_id;
    this.is_favorite = is_favorite;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.last_travel_mode = last_travel_mode;
    this.geometry = geometry;
    this.visited_count = visited_count;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you add `SearchData` code?

Comment: @Android777 Added my Model for SearchData

Comment: As a side note, I'm wondering why this model works since `Geometry` is definitely not the type supported by Realm, and it usually throws an error when building if you  don't @Ignore this field.

Comment: Oh, unless it's a RealmObject as well

Comment: Geometry is another Model class created by me, and it extends RealmObject. Everything from the model extends RealmObject, or is a primitive. This code used to work perfect until a couple of hours ago. I changed nothing in my code base. Even more, if I try an older already made apk it works, If I do a git reset, and try the same code as the older apk, it doesn't work.

Comment: What if you query the object afterwards? Do you get the expected result?

Comment: no, still False instead of True

Comment: PS: From time to time, I did manage to get the correct value, after adding to the server, but sometimes its false (most of the times), and somethimes it works fine. This behaviour is really strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SearchData` class has both `getIs_favorite()` and `is_favorite()`.

In that case, Realm annotation processor overrides only is_favorite().
That's why `getIs_favorite()` returns always `false`.